# Retrieving results from variations of system('top') returns errors

Tags: gvim, terminal, external-command, shell

Directly on the Ubuntu terminal, I can extract the results from `top` regarding a specific PID with:

```
top -p <pid> -n1 | awk '/<pid>/'
```

Where `<pid>` should be substituted with a PID number.

When I am inside gVim 8.1, I try doing the same with:

```
:call system("top -p <pid> -n1 | awk '\/<pid>\/'")
```

I use the backslashes to make the forward-slashes be interpreted correctly as the `/` character. However, to my surprise, I get the error:

> TERM environment variable not set

I found that to be odd, since things like `:call system("ps")` work perfectly.

If I try the same in terminal Vim 8.1, I get:

> top: failed tty get^@

But again all sorts of variations of `:call system("ps")` work well.

Why would that be the case and how could I make it work such that I retrieve the results of `system("top -p <pid> -n1 | awk '\/<pid>\/'")` inside a variable like:

```
let myvariable = system("top -p <pid> -n1 | awk '\/<pid>\/'")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`top` is a interactive program, so I'm not surprised it has problems when called in a non interactive shell without a terminal. Loosely speaking this is like

```sh
$ top -p 7783 -n1 </dev/null | awk "/7783/"
top: failed tty get
```

To use `top` like you want, add the option `-b` for "batch mode".

From the man page:

> **-b** Batch-mode operation 
>  
>   Starts top in Batch mode, which could be useful  for  sending
>   output  from  top  to  other  programs or to a file.  In this
>   mode, top will not accept input and runs until the iterations
>   limit  you've  set with the `-n' command-line option or until
>   killed.